# 'list' object has no attribute 'model'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to order all stories by average rating, when i type in url .../stories?ordering=average_rating it brings error: `'list' object has no attribute 'model'`

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Story.objects.all()
        ordering = self.request.query_params.get('ordering', None)
        if ordering == 'average_rating':
            return sorted(queryset, key=lambda s: s.average_rating)
        return queryset
```

```
class Story(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def average_rating(self):
        average_rating = self.ratings.all().aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']
        if average_rating is not None:
            return round(float(average_rating), 2)

        return None
```

Comment: Error message must be showing some line number in the code. Can you tell us which code statement is throwing the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name implies, `get_queryset` needs to return a queryset, not a list.

Luckily your entire query and ordering can be done in the database; you don't need the `average_rating` method.

```
    queryset = Story.objects.annotate(average_rating= Avg('ratings__rating'))
    ordering = self.request.query_params.get('ordering', None)
    if ordering == 'average_rating':
        queryset = queryset.order_by("average_rating")
    return queryset
```

Comment: i think that order_by works only with fields, not ```@property```

Comment: `order_by` works with fields and annotates. In Daniel's response, the average is computed in `average_rating` when queryset is built. You are not ordering through a property

Answer (score 2):

`sorted(queryset, key=lambda s: s.average_rating)` this returns a list, while `get_queryset` should return a `queryset`

You can try something like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Story.objects.all()
    ordering = self.request.query_params.get('ordering', None)
    if ordering == 'average_rating':
        return queryset.annotate(rating_avg=Avg('ratings__rating')).order_by('rating_avg')
    return queryset
```