# How to solve "List object has no model" error on Python?

Tags: python, list, model

I've been trying to make a flashcard maker which can make lots of language Anki flashcards in one go, but seem to have an issue where when it comes to writing to the file it says ''list' object has no attribute 'model'' on the output of the final section. I've tried a few things but don't seem to get it to work and have now been stuck for a week now. Can somebody help me please?

Code below:

```
# In[1]:


pip install genanki


# In[2]:


pip install dutch_words


# In[3]:


pip install translate


# In[4]:


import genanki


# In[5]:


import dutch_words


# In[6]:


from translate import Translator


# In[7]:


dutchwords = dutch_words.get_ranked()


# In[8]:


translator = Translator(from_lang = "nl", to_lang="en")


# In[9]:


my_model = genanki.Model(
  1607392319,
  'Simple Model',
  fields=[
    {'name': 'Question'},
    {'name': 'Answer'},],  templates=[
    {
      'name': 'Card 1',
      'qfmt': '{{Question}}',
      'afmt': '{{FrontSide}}<hr id="answer">{{Answer}}',
    },
  ])


# In[10]:


my_deck = genanki.Deck(
  2059400110,
  'Dutch Dictionary')


# In[11]:


mynotes = []
x = 0 
for x in range (10):
 my_note = genanki.Note(
  model=my_model,
  fields=[dutchwords[x], translator.translate(dutchwords[x])]), 
mynotes.append(my_note)

          


# In[12]:


my_deck = genanki.Deck(
  2059400115,
  'Dutch Dictionary')

my_deck.add_note(mynotes)


# In[13]:


genanki.Package(my_deck).write_to_file('DutchDictionary.apkg')
```

**and I get this error when running the In[13] section:**

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [13], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 genanki.Package(my_deck).write_to_file('DutchDictionary.apkg')

File ~\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject3\lib\site-packages\genanki\package.py:40, in Package.write_to_file(self, file, timestamp)
     37   timestamp = time.time()
     39 id_gen = itertools.count(int(timestamp * 1000))
---> 40 self.write_to_db(cursor, timestamp, id_gen)
     42 conn.commit()
     43 conn.close()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject3\lib\site-packages\genanki\package.py:60, in Package.write_to_db(self, cursor, timestamp, id_gen)
     57 cursor.executescript(APKG_COL)
     59 for deck in self.decks:
---> 60   deck.write_to_db(cursor, timestamp, id_gen)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject3\lib\site-packages\genanki\deck.py:61, in Deck.write_to_db(self, cursor, timestamp, id_gen)
     59 models = json.loads(models_json_str)
     60 for note in self.notes:
---> 61   self.add_model(note.model)
     62 models.update(
     63   {model.model_id: model.to_json(timestamp, self.deck_id) for model in self.models.values()})
     64 cursor.execute('UPDATE col SET models = ?', (json.dumps(models),))

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'model'
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that `my_deck.add_note()` is meant to be called with a single `Note` object, not a list of them.

Comment: Look here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58406804/list-object-has-no-attribute-model